# Image Smoothing in MPI using Scatter and Gather

Tags: mpi

Hello I have a task in MPI. In this task I will implement a parallel image processing algorithm. This algorihm calculates the average of each pixel's value and its eight neighbors. You can think of an image as a 2-dimensional array of color values, that is, a matrix, the smoothing algorithm can be applied to all values of this matrix, that is, the pixels of an image.

The figure below shows the softening process of the midpoint and is the average of 8 neighbors after softening. [3x3 Smoothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59J8D.png) (20+40+10+10+20+20+10+20+30)/9 = 20

My program applies a smoothing algorithm to the input image and then stores the results in a new image. So, I need to write a sequential program program.c that takes two inputs; first for the name of the input image and the second for the name of the output image. This section does not need to include any parallel processing.

I have two library for reading and writing:  [<stb_image.h>](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) and [<stb_image_write.h>](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h)

> mpcc task.c -lm -o task_mpi

> ./task_mpi -n 2 input.jpg output.jpg

I tried to work on the program a bit, but I could not make fruitful progress.

Mycode:

```
    #include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "stb_image.h"
#include "stb_image_write.h"
#define CHANNEL_NUM 1


    int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
        int width, height, bpp, total,rgb;
        MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
        int id ;
        int size;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&id);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
        int *img_mpi;
        int local_image = (height/3)*width / size;
        int* recv_buf = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*local_image);
        int full_image[height*width];
        // Reading the image
        uint8_t* rgb_image = stbi_load(argv[1], &width, &height, &bpp, CHANNEL_NUM);
        
        printf("Width: %d  Height: %d \n",width,height);
    
        for(int ii = 0; ii < height*width;ii++)
        {
            full_image[ii]=&rgb_image[ii];
        }
        
        MPI_Scatter(full_image, local_image ,MPI_INT, &recv_buf,local_image, MPI_INT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
        if(id == 1)
        {
            for(int i=1;i<height;i++)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<width;j++)
                {           
                    total = 
                            recv_buf,[(i-1)*width +(j-1)] + 
                            recv_buf,[(i-1)*width +j] +  
                            recv_buf,[(i-1)*width +(j+1)] + 
                            recv_buf,[(i)*width +(j-1)] + 
                            recv_buf,[i*width + j] +  
                            recv_buf,[(i)*width +(j+1)] + 
                            recv_buf,[(i+1)*width +(j-1)] + 
                            recv_buf,[(i+1)*width +j] +  
                            recv_buf,[(i+1)*width +(j+1)];
                    rgb = (total / 9);
                    recv_buf[i*width + j]= rgb;         
                }
            } 
        }
        MPI_Gather(&recv_buf, local_image ,MPI_INT, full_image, local_image, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         
        if(id == 0)
        {
            
                rgb_image = &recv_buf;
            
        }
        
        // Stoing the image 
        stbi_write_jpg(argv[2], width, height, CHANNEL_NUM, rgb_image, 100);
        stbi_image_free(rgb_image);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please help me...

Comment: `MPI_Gather()` is a collective operation and hence must be called by **all** the ranks of the communicator. That being said, I do not understand why you would issue a gather right after reading the image. Anyway, if you are stuck, provide a detail explanation of where you are at, what is working and what is not working.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure where to use this function.  I just tried somethings.

Comment: Why MPI_Comm_rank will be 0 or 1 ? and all seem to be storing the image.

Comment: I didnt run your code , if you use 1 thread, Does your code works?

Comment: I uptated with some errors. Could you check it.